# Chessclock time decrement

Tags: java, timer

I'm trying to build a chessclock to learn and I'm stuck with the code below. I'll use the actionListener like this. When "White" button is pressed, blackTime will decrement one every second, when "Black" button is pressed whiteTime will decrement one every second.

Right now my problem is to find a way to decrement time each second. I saw some questions like this and they talked about Timer class. I never used it and my understanding is it requires an ActionListener. I'm already using one so do I add another somehow or is there a simpler way?

Thanks!

```
public class ChessClock extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JPanel p;
JButton b1,b2;
JLabel l1;

public ChessClock(){
    super();
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(600,400);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    int whiteTime = 59;
    int blackTime = 59;

    p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    b1 = new JButton("White");
    b2 = new JButton("Black");

    l1 = new JLabel("00:" + whiteTime + " - " + "00:" + blackTime, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    l1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 85));

    b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
    b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.insets = new Insets(40,40,40,40);
    p.add(b1,c);
    p.add(b2,c);

    this.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(l1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //will later be used to switch between whiteTime - blackTime
    String s = e.getActionCommand();
        if(s == "White")
            s = s; 
        if(s == "Black")
        s = s;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html),

```
  int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          if(blackTurn)
             black--;
          else if(whiteTurn)
             white--;
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

I think in general you should avoid using `Thread.sleep()` and use the built in timer class! A while loop with `Thread.sleep()` will hold up the thread and wait, while timer will not.

So yes, create another action performed!

Answer (score 0):

How about a:

```
While(condition){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    if(//White button pressed){
        blackTime--;
    }else{
        whiteTime--;
}
```

It will wait 1s before doing the code below.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't use it but learned about it. It seems like the use of this is not recommended because it is wasteful.